Camel pubsub connect via external account (workload-identity-federation)
Does the camel-google-pubsub support external account(Workload Identity Federation) authorization?
I'm using camel-google-pubsub 3.21.0.
According to the document, It support service account
https://camel.apache.org/components/next/google-pubsub-component.html
But I found anther way:
Although GooglePubsubComponent only provides the setServiceAccountKey method, it does not provide a place to set the credentials path.
But we can do it through ADC.
If we do not set ServiceAccountKey, it will use getApplicationDefault, and getApplicationDefault uses the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to find credentials.
credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(ObjectHelper.isEmpty(endpoint.getServiceAccountKey())
                    ? GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault() : ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(ResourceHelper
                            .resolveMandatoryResourceAsInputStream(getCamelContext(), endpoint.getServiceAccountKey()))
                            .createScoped(PublisherStubSettings.getDefaultServiceScopes()));

So we only need to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to implement the external account authentication method.
Does this way is recommended?

HI , could you plz share the error message you are getting ?
